# DNS-related Latency Spikes in GKE Cluster with Cloudflare Proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, dns, google-kubernetes-engine, cloudflare

I have created a Node JS cron job that sends requests to my production environment API endpoints every minute, records the response time of each request and sends the value of that response time along with the requests timestamp to my Atlassian Statuspage system metrics API which displays this data in a graph.
These production API endpoints are hosted in a GKE cluster and the DNS records for the domain name of these endpoints are managed by Cloudflare.

The problem is that in specific times during the day, the graph is spiking - going from an average of 180ms per request to +2000ms per request.

I have checked the logs of the API endpoints in elastic APM and there is no increase in the response time of the endpoints themselves, so I'm assuming that the problem is with the DNS resolution of the domain name of the endpoints.
I have also tested the response times of the same API endpoints in a self-hosted Kubernetes cluster in Bare Metal servers and the average response times consists with the average response times of the endpoints in the GKE cluster when the graph is stable and there are no spikes in this graph.

Another thing I have done is rewrite the Node JS cron job in .NET 7 because I had doubts that the problem had something to do with the garbage collector of Node JS, but the problem persisted identically in both environments.

This led me to suspect an issue with DNS resolution for the domain names of these endpoints, especially since Cloudflare manages the DNS records and I've had similair issues with them in the past. To test this theory, I have also tried sending requests directly to the IP addesses of the corresponding GKE load balancer services which don't go through the Cloudflare proxy and in this case there were no major spikes or latencies.

Has anyone had a similar problem? What can I do to resolve these spikes?

Comment: Not enough details to answer. If this is a Cloudflare DNS problem, contact Cloudflare after collecting data that shows they are the problem. DNS resolvers cache responses from DNS servers. What are the TTL values on your DNS resource records? If the TTL values are normal (600 seconds or longer) then the problem might be with your system. You will need to do the analysis. Once you have a well-defined problem, post a question.